# Is there a better way to get TestEngine instance using the testEngineId in JUnit 5?

Tags: junit5

I'm developing a `TestExecutionListener` where I'd like to obtain the version of the `TestEngine` that executed that test (e.g., the `TestEngine` version).

I'm currently discovering all the available `TestEngine` using the `ServiceLocator` approach (similar to what the `Launcher` does) and iterating to extract those located engines into a map. Then, using the `testEngineId,` I can get the version.

I think this approach is too overkill, but I couldn't find anything better.

Is there a public API to get a `TestEngine` instance based on the `testEngineId`?

Comment: Can you describe the overall idea of what info you want to collect and to what end? That might help to find a more straightforward way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I would like to collect the version of the test engine. I'll edit the original message.

Comment: Having checked the current JUnit code I think using java.util.ServiceLoader is the best approach. If you cache the loaded engines it's not a lot of runtime overhead even if you get the engines in each call to TestExecutionListener.